# Shell keeps crashing over and over

Tags: kubuntu, kde, crash, plasma-5

The Plasma 5 shell in Kubuntu, or "plasmashell", keeps crashing repeatedly. I have a piece of information from the KDE crash handler that might help resolve this issue.

> **Plasma - The KDE Crash Handler**
>   We are sorry, Plasma closed unexpectedly.
>   You can help us improve KDE Software by reporting this error.
>   *Learn more about bug reporting.*
>   **Details:**
> Executable: plasmashell PID: 20139 Signal: Segmentation fault (11) Time: 9/7/19 11:55:03

That's the message displayed by the crash handler in the general tab. Developer information tab:

> **Plasma  The KDE Crash Handler**
>   The debugger has quit unexpectedly.
>   The crash information could not be generated
>   *Buttons:* Reload, Clipboard, Download
>   You could try to regenerate the backtrace by clicking the *Reload* button.
>   *Buttons:* Report Bug, Restart Application, Close

If any other information could be added to the post, then I will add it.

Comment: Are there some files in `/var/crash`?

Comment: A few files.  _usr_bin_budgie-daemon.1000.crash, _usr_budgie-polkit-dialog.1000.crash, _usr_bin_kglobalaccel5.1000.crash, _usr_bin_krunner.1000.crash, _usr_bin_light-locker.1000.crash, _usr_bin_sddm.1000.crash, _usr_bin_xscreensaver-demo.1000.crash, _usr_lib_jvm_java-8-openjdk-amd64_jre_bin_java.1000.crash, but I believe you're most interesed in **_usr_bin_plasmashell.1000.crash** and **_usr_bin_sddm.1000.crash**

Comment: Crash reports need to be filed with apport, and filed as crash bugs.  Not as questions here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You say Kubuntu but you list *…budgie-daemon…*, …budgie-polkit…, …light-locker…, …xscreensaver…. So is your "Kubuntu" a mélange of desktop environments?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, DK, but I will specify; I've used Ubuntu's after-login environment switching feature to add some more desktops.